# Different Uses of PowerShell With SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

Following the release of SharePoint 2010, there has been renewed interest in using PowerShell to manage SharePoint solutions.  I'm interested in finding out how my peers are currently using PowerShell with SharePoint, either 2007 or 2010.

For example, I use a PowerShell script to determine the number of sites, sub-sites and pages that have been created in specific web applications.  Can you provide details of how you make use of PowerShell?

Comment: Folks, if you're voting to close, I would appreciate at least a comment indicating why you think the question isn't suitable.  Thanks!

Comment: Some one vote to close as "Not a real" question. I feel it is a good question.

Comment: Good question but should be community wiki.

Comment: Filburt, if you can explain to me why this post should be a community wiki, I'll be happy to make it one.  Thanks.

Comment: Voting to close as "Not constructive". This is a poll.

Answer (score 1):

We're developing some custom SP2010 software. We're using Powershell cmdlets to install and upgrade builds on our test machines, as well as do some initial configuration tasks such as deploying features to certain webs, and creating service apps & service app proxies.

Unfortunately the cmdlets don't seem to play well with PSRemoting, which makes automated build & deploy trickier.

Answer (score 1):

I use PowerShell for installation and debugging purposes. I'm surprised that you haven't used Powershell with SharePoint 2010.

I write quite a few scripts for deploying and managing many solutions. For Example, Every time we deploy our PerformancePoint dashboards, it removes the top the global navigation. I use a Powershell script to re-insert the global navigation based on a XML File that I have created.